# What is scriptdb scope wrt users?

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm a little confused about the scope of a ScriptDB datastore.

I read that "Each script gets a database". Does that mean that multiple users of the same script are accessing the same database?

If yes, do I need to shard data somehow to give each user of a published script his own data subset?
If no, how do I implement a multi-user application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some testing, I've concluded that multiple users running the same script will be accessing the same datastore.

So, it seems that one would need to include a username as a field within the stored data and the include that field in any and all queries if one wants personal data.

During testing I hit what looks like a latency issue. Question here [Does apps script scriptdb have a latency factor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11266575/does-apps-script-scriptdb-have-a-latency-factor)

Answer (score 3):

If you read the FAQ here https://developers.google.com/apps-script/scriptdb#frequently_asked_questions that's exactly what I understood.

I even opened an issue for this: http://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=1482

Star the issue please if you agree.

Basically I think ScriptDB is analogous to Script Properties at this point. More complex obviously, but the same scope.