# Does apps script scriptdb have a latency factor?

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a script which adds a record to a ScriptDB datastore, then immediately queries all records and displays a count. 90% of the time, the displayed count is incremented as one would expect. However 10% of the time, the count is NOT incremented. Then on the next invocation the count is +2.

Answer (score 1):

ScriptDb is still in 'experimental' mode, I guess you should raise an issue on the [issue tracker](http://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/list) if you have experienced this repeatedly.

Comment: It may be that the count is being cached and is not being updated in time.